# Celery Error with EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a wrapper around `EmailMultiAlternatives` to make the interface a little bit cleaner (taken nearly verbatim from [here](http://ozkatz.github.io/getting-e-mail-right-with-django-and-ses.html)):

```
class Email(object):
    '''
    Wrapper around the Django core's EmailMultiAlternatives that makes it simpler
    to render txt and html templates.
    '''

    def __init__(self, to, subject):
        self.to = to
        self.subject = subject
        self.html = None
        self.text = None

    def _render(self, template, context):
        return render_to_string(template, context)

    def render_html(self, template, context):
        self.html = self._render(template, context)

    def render_text(self, template, context):
        self.text = self._render(template, context)

    def send(self, from_addr=None, fail_silently=False):
        if isinstance(self.to, basestring):
            self.to = [self.to]
        if not from_addr:
            from_addr = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
            self.subject,
            self.text,
            from_addr,
            self.to
        )
        if self.html:
            msg.attach_alternative(self.html, 'text/html')
        msg.send(fail_silently)
```

I call it like this:

```
   if not self.email:
        warnings.warn('uid:%s has no email address' % self.id)
    else:
        context = Context({
            'first_name': self.first_name,
            'uid': int_to_base36(self.id),
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(self),
            'domain': Site.objects.get_current().domain
        })

        from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
        subject = "Password Reset"
        email = Email(to=self.email, subject=subject)
        email.render_text('email/reset_password_email.txt', context)
        email.render_html('email/reset_password_email.html', context)
        email.send()
```

I'm using django-celery-email, which simply provides a wrapper around Django's built in send email function to turn it into a celery worker task. However, when I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: <django.core.mail.message.EmailMultiAlternatives object at 0x10c20f3d0> is not JSON serializable
```

This occurs within the context of creating the celery task. I'm not sure what's going on here. When I don't use EmailMultiAlternatives and simply use Django's built in send_mail (which also gets wrapped as a celery task by django-celery-email), I don't get the error. Thoughts?

Comment: This should work with pickling instead of JSON-serializing. Celery is trying to serialize your task.  Check out the docs: http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#calling-serializers

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried to inherit your `Email` class from the `EmailMultiAlternatives`? By doing that you still implement the methods used for celery.